# Factoring Numbers with inner nulls

Tags: prime-factorization

Just imagine I have two primes, $p$ and $q$, each $1400$ bits long.

Each has the middle $1000$ bits set to $0$.  Thus the top $200$ and bottom $200$ bits are meaningful in each number.

Take $s=pq$.

Would it be trivial given $s$, to determine what $p$ and $q$ were?

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a decimal example, with shorter numbers: $36037007$ is the product of two primes $a \times 10^3 + b$ and $c \times 10^3 + d$, where $a, b, c, d$ are single digits.  Find $a, b, c, d$.

We have
$$(a \times 10^3 + b)(c \times 10^3 + d) = ac \times 10^6 + (ad+bc) \times 10^3 + bd$$
and so we must have $ac = 36, bd = 7, ad + bc = 37$.

Therefore $c = 36/a, d = 7/b$ and so we have to solve

$$ a(7/b) + b(36/a) = 37 $$

Let $a/b = x$.  Then we have $7x + 36/x = 37$.  Multiply through by $x$ and rearrange to get $7x^2 - 37x + 36 = 0$.  It turns out that this has solutions $x =  9/7$ and $x = 4$.

From $x = 9/7$ we can recover $a/b = 9/7$, and since we know $a \times 10^3 + b$ is prime we must have $a = 9, b= 7$.  Similarly from $x = 4$ we get $a = 4, b = 1$.  Thus we have $36037007 = 9007 \times 4001$.

Consider alternatively $36035007$, which is not such a product.  Going through the same procedure we get $7x^2 - 35x + 36 = 0$, and this doesn't have rational solutions since $35^2 - 4 \times 7 \times 36 = 217$ is not a square.

This will generalize to factoring $(xn^2 + yn + z)$ into factors $an+b$ and $cn+d$ as long as $a, b, c, d$ are sufficiently small - I believe $a, b, c, d < \sqrt{n/2}$ works.   And this method does not require any factoring, only simple arithmetic and testing if a number is square.

Answer (score 0):

Let $m=200$, $n=1200$.
You have
$$\begin{align}
    p &= 2^n a + b & 0 < a &< 2^m & 0 < b &< 2^m
\\  q &= 2^n c + d & 0 < c &< 2^m & 0 < d &< 2^m
\end{align}$$
Therefore
$$s = pq = 2^{2n}ac + 2^n(ad+bc) + bd$$
where
$$\begin{align}
    0 < ac &< 2^{2m} & 0 < ad+bc &< 2^{2m+1} & 0 < bd &< 2^{2m}
\end{align}$$
Since $2m+1\leq n$,
you can read off $ac$ by discarding the lowest $2n$ bits of $s$.
And $bd$ by discarding all but the lowest $2m$ bits of $s$.
And $ad+bc$ by reading bits $n\ldots(n+2m)$ of $s$.

Now you can compute
$$\begin{align}
    |ad-bc| &= \sqrt{(ad+bc)^2 - 4(ac)(bd)}
\\  \{ad, bc\} &= \frac{(ad+bc) \pm |ad-bc|}{2}
\end{align}$$
Now we have $(ac,ad,bc,bd)$,
except that we do not know which of $\{ad,bc\}$ is which.
Let's just make an arbitrary choice there.

Since $p$ is prime, $a$ and $b$ must be coprime.
Similarly, since $q$ is prime, $c$ and $d$ must be coprime.
Therefore
$$\begin{align}
    a &= a\gcd(c,d) = \gcd(ac,ad)
&   b &= b\gcd(c,d) = \gcd(bc,bd)
\\  c &= \gcd(a,b)\,c = \gcd(ac,bc)
&   d &= \gcd(a,b)\,d = \gcd(ad,bd)
\end{align}$$
from which you can recover $p$ and $q$.

If $ad$ and $bc$ are swapped (as allowed by the $\pm$),
then the subsequent determination of $a,b,c,d$ simply swaps
$a$ with $c$ and $b$ with $d$ and therefore swaps $p$ and $q$,
which is as it should be.

Once you have determined $a$, you can as well use
$$\begin{align}
    c &= \frac{ac}{a};
&   b &= \frac{bc}{c};
&   d &= \frac{bd}{b} = \frac{ad}{a}
\end{align}$$
This ensures $pq=s$ even if you do not know whether $p$ and $q$ are prime.

This method works as long as we know that more than the middle third of the
factor bitstrings are zeroed.